# Open Source Linux network analyzer

Tags: linux, networking, open-source, network-monitoring, analysis

Open Source Linux network analyzer

Which are there? What features do they offer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What exactly do you need?

- [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - network sniffer/analyzer
- iftop - bandwidth usage
- darkstat - traffic analyzer
- nmap - network port scanner
- nessus - vulnerability scanner
- metasploit - penetration testing

Comment: Worked for me, thx

Answer (score 5):

Can't believe nobody mentioned [tcpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump). Click on the link to see the list of features

Comment: Surprised by that too

Answer (score 4):

ntop is a solution that has been around for a while, can be extended with plugins.  [Here is a short how-to](http://www.howtoforge.com/network_monitoring_with_ntop).

Answer (score 3):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) (formerly ethereal) is my favorite.

Answer (score 3):

A few more:

- lanmap2 - sits quietly on a network and builds a picture of what it sees.
- kismet - wireless sniffer
- nikto - web server scanner
- nast - another network sniffer/analyzer

Answer (score 1):

A missing tool from the list is `ettercap`. A text-based tool to analyse a subnet and perform active or passive scans of the subnet. It can also monitor packets and display streams.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a network traffic analyzer you can use tshark (it's the console version of wireshark).

Answer (score 0):

MRTG for nice pretty pictures and graphs (management p0rn) via SNMP monitoring. does everything i need, but if u dont list your requirements its quite hard to guess what you want.

Answer (score 0):

p0f - passive OS fingerprinting (http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

for reconaissance / mostly real time analysis:

- [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) - text-only version of [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) when tcpdump is too cryptic.
- [httpry](http://dumpsterventures.com/jason/httpry/) - simple nice passive http protocol sniffer.
- [ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/) - displays payload of selected traffic

Answer (score 0):

If you need a network intrusion IDS/IPS tool, Snort is one such open source tool.